# Click label causes img to move up

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have a browser problem in IE7 which you can view here: http://jsfiddle.net/SZDDm/1/

The problem is when you click the label surrounding the image and checkbox, the image will move up in position.

What is causing this?

Comment: Never seen that before, how bizarre..

Comment: It's odd...I saw it happen on all of them, refreshed and now it only happens randomly on some of them. I even tried closing the browser and opening a new instance but it still only happens some of the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In class `#searchDeals .networks label` change height to `56px`. That will fix the issue.

The problem is the `margin: 4px auto` which you have for **INPUT**.

Just give it `margin: 4px auto 0 auto`.

http://jsfiddle.net/SZDDm/23/

For the reason this happens, check this link:
http://www.brunildo.org/test/margins_clear.html

Comment: This certainy appears to work but can anyone shed any light as to what is the cause? Is IE7 adding additional padding/margin when the checkbox is checked?